# How to make indent-region keep the TAB in Makefile buffer?

Tags: tabs, makefile-mode, indentation

A very simple Makefile:

```
all:
        gcc -o hello hello.c
```

And I already set:

```el
(add-hook 'before-save-hook
      '(lambda ()
         (delete-trailing-whitespace)
         ;; indent the whole buffer before-save
         (when (derived-mode-p 'prog-mode)
           (indent-region (point-min) (point-max)))))
```

in my `init.el`, so if I `C-x C-s` in this Makefile file, it will become:

```
all:
gcc -o hello hello.c
```

Is there a way I can make Emacs recognize that the lines under `:` symbol should be indented with one TAB?

BTW: Typing TAB in the `gcc...` line will keep inserting tabs, is there a way that typing TAB indents this line like doing it in C code and TAB again won't do anything like inserting another tab)?

Comment: Indentation is a makefile is not deterministic, as in emacs can't know whether or not that line should or shouldn't be indented. This applies to other whitespace dependent language like python, take a line of python and improperly indent it, there could be many levels of indentation that are syntactically correct for a given line, but emacs has no way to know which one is correct without understanding the context of your application. However, for simple makefiles, you could write your own `indent-line-function` that always indents lines with one tab if they come after a make target.

Comment: @JordonBiondo How can I exclude `makefile-mode` from '(derived-mode-p 'prog-mode)' then?

Comment: Check against the `major-mode` variable. So something like: `(unless (eq major-mode 'makefile-mode) ...)`. Note that there are actually a number of makefile major modes, so you'll need check whether or not any of them are the major mode like `(unless (member major-mode the-list-of-makefile-major-modes) ...)`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jordonbiondo/dc4482f07c48cf9ee59a. I won't post this as answer for now, hoping that someone chimes with something that isn't "you can't"

Comment: @JordonBiondo Thanks, and I modified my snippet of code a little bit, and it works as expected.